# encodeURIComponent double quotation process

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

Encoded with encodeURIComponent in javascript to handle double-quote at the time of
Questions.
Was treated as follows: If you have double quotes in the save point andoeneyo ...
Can I be treated?
"TEST" this problem.

---

```
var point = "homepage|"TEST"|1|0|#ffffff";

var upsert_domain = _JSON_SCRIPT_DOMAIN + "/back/insert_new.jsp?proc_id=deal3_insert&query_type=update&data=";

upsert_domain +="[{\"point_info\":\""+encodeURIComponent(point)+"\"}]";


var oParam_corp = { url: upsert_domain };


$.ajax({
          type:"POST",
          async : false,
          url:_PROXY_URL,
          dataType:"json",
          timeout : 10000,
          cache : false,
          data:oParam_corp,
          contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
          ,success: function(data) {
              if(data[0].result == "200")
                {
                  registerCoperation(url);
                }
          }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your string enclosing quotes are wrong - since you are using `"` inside the string enclose the literal with `''`

```
var point = 'homepage|"TEST"|1|0|#ffffff';
var upsert_domain = _JSON_SCRIPT_DOMAIN + "/back/insert_new.jsp?proc_id=deal3_insert&query_type=update&data=";

upsert_domain += '[{"point_info":"' + encodeURIComponent(point) +'"}]';
```